# Python dataframe delete sentences number from list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, apply, spacy

I have a column of (quite) long texts in a dataframe, and for each text, a list of sentences indexes that I would like to delete. The sentences indexes were generated by Spacy when I split texts into sentences. Please consider the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

data = {'text': ['I am A. I am 30 years old. I live in NY.','I am B. I am 25 years old. I live in SD.','I am C. I am 30 years old. I live in TX.'], 'todel': [[1, 2], [1], [1, 2]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def get_sentences(text):
    text_clean = nlp(text)
    sentences = text_clean.sents
    sents_list = []
    for sentence in sentences:
        sents_list.append(str(sentence))
    return sents_list

df['text'] = df['text'].apply(get_sentences)

print(df)
```

which gives the following:

```
                                           text   todel
0  [I am A., I am 30 years old., I live in NY.]  [1, 2]
1   [I am B. I am 25 years old., I live in SD.]     [1]
2   [I am C. I am 30 years old., I live in TX.]  [1, 2]
```

How would you delete the sentences stored in `todel` efficiently, knowing that I have a very large dataset with more than 50 sentences to drop for each row ?

My expected output would be:

```
                                  text   todel
0                      [I live in NY.]  [1, 2]
1  [I am 25 years old., I live in SD.]     [1]
2                      [I live in TX.]  [1, 2]
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I added that in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer of @user1740577:

```
def fun(sen, lst):
    return [i for j, i in enumerate(sen) if j not in lst]

df['text'] = df.apply(lambda row : fun(row['text'],row['todel']), axis=1)
```

Yields the wanted result, based on the indexing of Spacy:

```
                           text    todel
0                     [I am A.]   [1, 2]
1  [I am B. I am 25 years old.]      [1]
2  [I am C. I am 30 years old.]   [1, 2]
```